# Using lapply to apply functions across lists in R?

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a data frame loaded into R with different values by group:

```
Group Value
A     50
A     2
A     55
B     41
B     60
B     102
C     24
C     60
C     2
D     6
D     9
D     20
E     1
E     23
E     19
```

I am using a split function to split the data by group:

```
mylist <- split(mydata, mydata$Group)
mylist
```

I am then creating an auto.arima function that works and returns ARIMA output when I run it on an individual group (with the group already being loaded into R as a separate dataframe):

```
arm <- function(x) auto.arima(x)
forecastarm=arm(myTableA$Value)
```

However, what I want to do is use the ARIMA function to calculate ARIMA on all the groups in the dataset automatically. However, I am unsure how to use lapply to do this.

I have tried:

```
allarima <- lapply(mylist,arm)
```

However, it does not seem to be running the ARIMA models separately across group like I want, as I am getting the error message:

```
Error in auto.arima(x) : No suitable ARIMA model found
```

Would be grateful for any help on how to use lapply correctly with the function. Many thanks.

Comment: do you want the function to use the `Value` column? ie  `arm <- function(x) auto.arima(x$Value)`

Comment: Bingo. I was working through the problem since posting, and had noticed that the function was calculating on unsuitable variables as well, such as Date, Name, etc. Specifying the value column in the function fixed the problem, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out.

I was trying to run the function on the whole data frame, when I should have been isolating the Value column and simply running it on that.

```
mylist <- split(mydata, mydata$Group)
mylist

arm <- function(x) plot(forecast(auto.arima(x$Value),h))
allarima <- lapply(mylist,arm)
```

You can see that in the function, I specified auto.arima(x$Value), as opposed to simply **x** which represents the entire data frame.

Moreover, instead of simply obtaining the ARIMA output, I wanted to get the forecasts and plots directly so called the plot and forecast functions using the pre-defined forecast period **h**.

Hope the above is informative, and many thanks to user20650 for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
mylist %>% 
  split(.$Group) %>% 
  map(~auto.arima(.$Value))
```

Btw...this is a canonical example in Garrett and Hadley’s ‘R for Data Science’

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `split` followed with `lapply` can be replaced with `by` (the object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`) which can slice a dataframe by factor(s) and pass subsets into a defined or anonymous function for further processing.

```
arm <- function(x) auto.arima(x$Value)

aroma_list <- by(mydata, mydata$Group, FUN = arm)
```